# how to obtain remote access port in azure webservice

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I deployed a web service, I enabled remote access. I can connect to the VM through the MS remote connector using the file downloaded from portal.
**But where I can find the VM remote access port?**
the "connect" filed downloaded from Azure portal do not include PORT.

any Idea?

Comment: Which Azure service are you actually using? (1) Azure Virtual Machine, (2) Azure Cloud Service or (3) Azure Web App?

Comment: @AlexLau Azure Cloud Service

Answer (score -1):

You can find the enabled endpoints inside the cloud service dashboard under input endpoints on the right.

RDP is usually 3389. Azure RDP is a bit more complicated than usual, since the file you download to connect to a particular instance contains routing information that defines how the client will connect to the particular instance since the cloud service has a single public ip and a single port which is load balanced between the instances.

You will find that it is quite hard to setup the RDP connection in a third party app without somehow using the downloaded file.

Comment: Yes I see that it is hard to setup in third party, this why I'm asking here maybe someone know how :(

Comment: It depends on what the remote desktop client is, so you might want to include this in your question. (i.e. remote desktop client for mac works fine)